# If $(a_n)$ is positive and $\sum\limits_n \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converges then $\sum\limits_n a_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I need to either prove the following or find a counterexample. I really hope you can help, I cannot figure it out.

> Let $(a_n)$ be a positive sequence.
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$$
>   converges, then
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
>   converges

Comment: First prove that $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: Adam Hughes' answer shows the hypothesis that $a_n>0$ is necessary, and gives $a_n = (-1)^n/n$ as a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.**

When $x$ is positive and $\frac{x}{1+x}$ is sufficiently small, we have $0 < x < 2\frac{x}{1+x} $.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that such series converges. Note then that since $a_n+1> 1$, we must have that $a_n\to 0$. But then the quotient of $a_n$ with $a_n/(1+a_n)$ tends to $1$.